Can you have a generic type parameter on a C# operator overload?
I'm toying around with an API design and I'd really like to support + for concatenation between two generic types.
public class Query<T>
{
    public static Query<S> operator+ <R, S>(Query<T> q, SomeOtherObject<R> s) where R : ...
                                  // ^ C# compiler doesn't allow this
}

Is this possible with some other syntax I'm not getting right?

No the syntax doesn't allow it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#15104-conversion-operators nor do I see how it would make sense

You can declare an operator as long as the types are the same: Query<T> operator+ (Query<T> q, SomeOtherObject<T> s). But I do not think there is any way to declare new generic parameters for an operator. You might want to take a look at how IAdditionOperators in generic math works.

I wonder how you would implement that operator for - say - MyClass + DateTime . So you need some constraint for your type-parameters, which effectivly limits the posible types to these that already do implement these operators.
